# Share params state between stack navigators in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How do I share params from a stack navigator to several stack navigators nested within a tab navigator?

```
const UsersStack = createStackNavigator(...)
const PostsStack = createStackNavigator(...)
const AlbumsStack = createStackNavigator(...)
const ToDosStack = createStackNavigator(...)

const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  PostsStack,
  AlbumsStack,
  ToDosStack
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    User: UsersStack,
    Main: MainTabNavigator
  })
);
```

From the `UsersScreen` within the `UsersStack`, I'm using..

```
navigation.navigate("Main", { userId: "1" })
```

Arrives at `PostsScreen` within `PostsStack` with no params

```
navigation.navigate("Posts", { userId: "1" })
```

Arrives at `PostsScreen` within `PostsStack` with params available, but only on the `PostsStack`. Switching tabs to either `AlbumsStack` or `ToDosStack` shows no params available.

Expected output is to have `userId` params available on all stacks.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Create context and hold your userid then wrap Stack Navigation component inside `Context.Provider`

```
import NavigationContext from './components/MyContext'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContext.Provider value={{
        "userId": "1"
      }}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </NavigationContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Now to consume `userId` use `Context.Consumer` that will receives the current context value and returns it to all stacknavigator screens

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import NavigationContext from './MyContext'
export default class UserScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  _navigate = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContext.Consumer>
        {
          ({ userId }) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Page  1</Text>
                <Text>{`UserId ${userId}`}</Text>
                <Button onPress={this._navigate} title="Navigate to page 2" />
              </View>)
          }
        }
      </NavigationContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

See example from here https://snack.expo.io/@selvaganesh93/navigationglobalcontextdemo